# Serilog RollingFile

Tags: c#, .net, serilog

I am trying to use `WriteTo.RollingFile` with Serilog as the following to write one file per day:

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.RollingFile(
                    @"F:\logs\log-{Date}.txt",
                    LogEventLevel.Debug).CreateLogger();
            log.Information("this is a log test");
```

But I am getting a new log file **for each log entry** during the same day!

How does one configure Serilog to write to a new file every day as to have a have a single log file per day?

---

And is there any archiving process to delete files older than 7 days?

Comment: Also, you need to make sure you only configure the log once, and then keep re-using the same `log` instance for all messages. HTH!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Try below:

```
 var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
          .MinimumLevel.Debug()
          .WriteTo.File(@"f:\log\log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day) 
          .CreateLogger();
```

The log file name  will be automatically log-20150819.txt etc. You do not need to specify the date.Old files will be cleaned up as per retainedFileCountLimit - default is 31.

Comment: This solves one of his questions. The other is a question that I also had about multiple log files being created in the same day. But one of the comments nailed it on the head. Configure only once and use the same log instances for all messages. I have configured once but I'm trying to figure out how to use it throughout the application. If I don't configure in each class then logging stops. It's due to my in-experience.

Comment: WriteTo.RollingFile  is now Deprecated read the Github page:  https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-rollingfile

Comment: Rather use Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()........ This way you have a global handle and you use it like this: Log.Information("Hello"); or Log.Error("This is an error");

Comment: "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true helped me

Answer (score 36):

#### WriteTo.RollingFile Deprecated

Since the posted answer, the method `RollingFile` is no longer viable and replaced with `File` and options to roll the logs.

Now one must use the standard `Serilog.Sinks.File` NuGet package which supports rolling:

```
.WriteTo.File(path: @"e:\logs\skilliam.log", 
              rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
              rollOnFileSizeLimit: true, 
              fileSizeLimitBytes: 123456);
```

Comment: It's in `Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile` now (without `rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day` it seems).

Comment: @YahooSerious, but how do you define the period of rolling?

Comment: According to https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-rollingfile, you 
use `{Date}`, `{Hour}` or `{HalfHour}`.  But they also state it's 
deprecated.  So I tried your code again, and it works now. I wonder why it did not work for me the first time. Maybe another package/version, or maybe I tried `RollingFile` instead of `File`?  Well, I guess that's "water under the bridge".

Answer (score 6):

Here is a way to use Serilog with a web.config in an asp.net MVC 4/5 app.

In your web.config add the following:

```
<add key="serilog:minimum-level" value="Information" />
<add key="serilog:minimum-level:override:Microsoft" value="Information" />
<add key="serilog:minimum-level:override:System" value="Information" />
<add key="serilog:using:RollingFile" value="Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.pathFormat" value="./Logs/log-{Date}.txt" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.outputTemplate" value="{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] [{SourceContext}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.retainedFileCountLimit" value="10" />
```

Then in `Application_Start` of global.asax add the following:

```
// Get application base directory
string basedir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

// Setup Serilog for logging
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
            .WriteTo.RollingFile(basedir + "/Logs/log-{Date}.txt")
            .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: `NET Core, NET5-6-7` use ***appsettings.json***

Answer (score 6):

**To enable multi-process shared log files, set shared to true:**

in code

```cs
.WriteTo.RollingFile("log-{Date}.txt", shared: true)
```

or in web.config

```xml
<add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.shared" value="true" />
```

Comment: how can i set shared property via appsetting.json, can you pls giv a sample.. I tried this, but it doesnt work..  "Name": "RollingFile",
        "Args": {
          "pathFormat": "D:\\Log-{Date}.json",
    "shared": "true"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40880261/configuring-serilog-rollingfile-with-appsettings-json

Comment: multi-process shared log files for Blazor app (web) ?

Answer (score 5):

To use the same file, you have to add  `shared: true`

> .WriteTo.RollingFile("log-{Date}.txt", shared: true)

Answer (score 3):

### WriteTo.RollingFile Deprecated -> With Formatter

If one is using a text formatter `ITextFormatter`, note that the variable positions of the `path` has switched to be second place when using `File`.

So use this format with a formatter:

```
var filepath = @"C:\Logs";
ITextFormatter jsonFormatter = new Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter(renderMessage: true);

...

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                  ... // Enrichers etc...
                 .WriteTo.File(formatter: jsonFormatter,
                               path: filepath,                            
                               rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                               rollOnFileSizeLimit: true, 
                               fileSizeLimitBytes: 123456,
                               shared: true)
                 .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: In aoosettings.json add an Args "shared":"true".

Answer (score 2):

As a follow up to this make sure you then use the globally scoped "Log" instance.

Example:

```
Log.Information("Hello world");
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all.
You need to add these nugets:

```
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="6.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Environment" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Process" Version="2.0.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Thread" Version="3.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="3.4.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="5.0.0" />
```

Than set your serilog in appsettings.json:

```
 "Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.Console",
      "Serilog.Sinks.File"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "Path": "../Logs/MyLog-.json",
          "RollingInterval": "Day",
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "Path": "../Logs/MyLog-.log",
          "RollingInterval": "Day",
          "OutputTemplate": "[({Component}|{MachineName}|{ThreadId}) {Timestamp:G} [{Level:u3}]{Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception} ]"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Than you need to add this config in C# code.

```
var _logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom
            .Configuration(configuration)
            .Enrich
            .FromLogContext()
            .CreateLogger();
        services.AddLogging(logBuilder => logBuilder.AddSerilog(_logger));


configuration is an instance of IConfiguration, u will find builder.Configuration
services --> builder.Services
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how I did it:

```
private readonly Serilog.ILogger _logger; //= Log.ForContext( "Name", "Weather" );

public WeatherForecastController() {
  string subPath = Path.Combine( DateTime.Now.ToString( "yyyy" ), DateTime.Now.ToString( "MM" ) ) + $"/{DateTime.Now.ToString("dd")}_Weather";
  _logger = Log.ForContext( "Name", subPath );
}
```

---

```
  .UseSerilog( ( hostingContext, loggerConfiguration ) => loggerConfiguration
    .ReadFrom.Configuration( hostingContext.Configuration )
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .WriteTo.Map(
      "Name",
      "Request",
      ( name, wt ) => {
        if (name == "Request")
          wt.RollingFile( Path.Combine( $"{hostingContext.Configuration["LogPath"]}/{{Date}}-{name}.txt" ) );
        else
          wt.File( $"{hostingContext.Configuration["LogPath"]}/{name}.txt" );
      } )
  );
```

Comment: Welcome! Please note that the [policy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/) is that [questions and answers need to be in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange). Please also [explain while your code is a solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). Some additional context helps a lot for others who will look at this later to understand why and how this solves the problem.