# Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'Serilog.Core.IDestructuringPolicy'

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

From studying [Serilog.Sinks.AzureTableStorage](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-azuretablestorage/tree/master) I have the following

In Main

```
 var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration) // the error happens here
            .CreateLogger();

        logger.Information("Hello, world!");
```

In appsetttings.json  ( with different connection string)

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.AzureTableStorage" ],
   
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": { "path": "%TEMP%\\Logs\\serilog-configuration-sample.txt" }
      },
      {
        "Name": "AzureTableStorage",
        "Args": {
          "storageTableName": "mystoragetable",
          "connectionString": "myconnectionstring"
                }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ],
    "Destructure": [
      {
        "Name": "With",
        "Args": { "policy": "Sample.CustomPolicy, Sample" }
      },
      {
        "Name": "ToMaximumDepth",
        "Args": { "maximumDestructuringDepth": 4 }
      },
      {
        "Name": "ToMaximumStringLength",
        "Args": { "maximumStringLength": 100 }
      },
      {
        "Name": "ToMaximumCollectionCount",
        "Args": { "maximumCollectionCount": 10 }
      }
    ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "Sample"
    }    
  }
```

I see in the debug output yet no data gets logged to the storage table.

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
>
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
>
> Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'Serilog.Core.IDestructuringPolicy'.

[Update]

If I use a very simple config as per the ReadMe.Md in GitHub, I get the same error.

[Update]

I copied in the code from Kennyzx link. The error has changed to

```
System.InvalidCastException
  HResult=0x80004002
  Message=Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'Serilog.Core.ILogEventFilter'.
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
```

I decided to try upgrading the serilog-settings-configuration sample project to .netcore2.1  and thus asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53126146/change-target-framework-from-net46netcoreapp2-1)

After a few hours I came to the conclusion that serilog-settings-configuration s is not compatible with dotnetcore 2.1

Comment: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-console/issues/28

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40880261/configuring-serilog-rollingfile-with-appsettings-json?rq=1

Comment: What is the definition for the interface 'Serilog.Core.IDestructuringPolicy'?  Can you post the code?

Comment: I downloaded the code from github and the interface is not present. The code uses .NetCoreApp 1.0 I am using 2.1.403

Comment: I guess the problem must be that I use a different version of .netcore

Comment: Try [this sample](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/tree/dev/sample/Sample).

Comment: @kennyzx Thank you, I updated the question.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I try to set up a new .NET Core 2.1 Console project called [UseSerilog](https://github.com/kennyzx/DotNetCore/tree/master/UseSerilog) and I can reproduce the issue.

After I remove the `Destructure` and `Filter` sections from the configuration then the app begins to work.

Then I check the source code of the `Serilog.Settings.Configuration` package, I find [this commit](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/commit/43345f15222cfc8a9188f16b023f44d3bf9c43e7), and I come to conclusion that you need to write some code in order to make it work like this way.

For the below configuration, you are expected to write a `CustomPolicy` class in the "Sample" namespace that implements `IDestructuringPolicy`.

```
{
    "Name": "With",
    "Args": { "policy": "Sample.CustomPolicy, Sample" }
}
```

If you remove this, and leave `Destructure` as below, it is working.

```
"Destructure": [
  {
    "Name": "ToMaximumDepth",
    "Args": { "maximumDestructuringDepth": 3 }
  },
  {
    "Name": "ToMaximumStringLength",
    "Args": { "maximumStringLength": 10 }
  },
  {
    "Name": "ToMaximumCollectionCount",
    "Args": { "maximumCollectionCount": 5 }
  }
]
```

Hope this finding helps you.

Comment: Thank you. It worked with the CustomPolicy too, once I realised I had to write it.