# Serilog logging web-api methods, adding context properties inside middleware

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, serilog, asp.net-core-middleware

I've been struggling to log response body payload data with serilog, logging from middleware.
I'm working on *WEB API Core* application, with *swagger* added to endpoints, and my goal is to log every endpoint call to a *.json* file with *serilog* (both request and response data).

For *GET* requests, body of the response should be logged (added to serilog context as a property), and for POST requests, both body of request and response should be logged.
I have created middleware and managed to properly retrieve data from request and response stream, and getting it as a string, but only the *"RequestBody"* is being logged properly.

When debugging, I can see that reading request/response body works fine.

Following is the code excerpt from Program->Main method:

```cs
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .CreateLogger();
```

and code in the middleware:

```cs
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    // Read and log request body data
    string requestBodyPayload = await ReadRequestBody(context.Request);

    LogContext.PushProperty("RequestBody", requestBodyPayload);

    // Read and log response body data
    var originalBodyStream = context.Response.Body;
    using (var responseBody = new MemoryStream())
    {
        context.Response.Body = responseBody;
        await _next(context);
        string responseBodyPayload = await ReadResponseBody(context.Response);

        if (!context.Request.Path.ToString().EndsWith("swagger.json") && !context.Request.Path.ToString().EndsWith("index.html"))
        {
            LogContext.PushProperty("ResponseBody", responseBodyPayload);
        }

        await responseBody.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);
    }
}

private async Task<string> ReadRequestBody(HttpRequest request)
{
    HttpRequestRewindExtensions.EnableBuffering(request);

    var body = request.Body;
    var buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(request.ContentLength)];
    await request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    string requestBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
    body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    request.Body = body;

    return $"{requestBody}";
}

private async Task<string> ReadResponseBody(HttpResponse response)
{
    response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    string responseBody = await new StreamReader(response.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    return $"{responseBody}";
}
```

As I mentioned, *"RequestBody"* is properly logged to file, but nothing for *"ResponseBody"* (not even added as a property)
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After collecting informations from several posts, and customizing it to my needs, I have found a way to log both request and response body data as properties of serilog log structure.

I didn't find a way to log both request and response body in one place only (in the `Invoke` method of the middleware), but I found a workaround. Because of the nature of the request processing pipeline, here is what I had to do:

Code in the `Startup.cs`:

```cs
app.UseMiddleware<RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware>();
app.UseSerilogRequestLogging(opts => opts.EnrichDiagnosticContext = LogHelper.EnrichFromRequest);
```

- I have used `LogHelper` class for enriching request properties, just as described in the [Andrew Locks post](https://andrewlock.net/using-serilog-aspnetcore-in-asp-net-core-3-logging-the-selected-endpoint-name-with-serilog/).
- when request processing hits the middleware, in the middleware's `Invoke` method I am reading **only request body data**, and setting this value to a static string property that I've added to `LogHelper` class. This way I have read and stored request body data as string, and can add it as enricher when `LogHelper.EnrichFromRequest` method gets called
- after reading request body data, I am copying a pointer to the original response body stream
- `await _next(context);` gets called next, `context.Response` is populated, and request processing exits out from middleware's `Invoke` method, and goes to `LogHelper.EnrichFromRequest`
- at this moment `LogHelper.EnrichFromRequest` is executing, **reading response body data** now, and setting it as enricher, as well as previously stored request body data and some additional properties
- processing returns to middleware `Invoke` method (right after `await _next(context);`), and copying the contents of the new memory stream (which contains the response) to the original stream,

Following is the code described above in `LogHelper.cs` and `RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware.cs` classes:

LogHelper.cs:

```cs
public static class LogHelper
{
    public static string RequestPayload = "";

    public static async void EnrichFromRequest(IDiagnosticContext diagnosticContext, HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var request = httpContext.Request;

        diagnosticContext.Set("RequestBody", RequestPayload);

        string responseBodyPayload = await ReadResponseBody(httpContext.Response);
        diagnosticContext.Set("ResponseBody", responseBodyPayload);

        // Set all the common properties available for every request
        diagnosticContext.Set("Host", request.Host);
        diagnosticContext.Set("Protocol", request.Protocol);
        diagnosticContext.Set("Scheme", request.Scheme);

        // Only set it if available. You're not sending sensitive data in a querystring right?!
        if (request.QueryString.HasValue)
        {
            diagnosticContext.Set("QueryString", request.QueryString.Value);
        }

        // Set the content-type of the Response at this point
        diagnosticContext.Set("ContentType", httpContext.Response.ContentType);

        // Retrieve the IEndpointFeature selected for the request
        var endpoint = httpContext.GetEndpoint();
        if (endpoint is object) // endpoint != null
        {
            diagnosticContext.Set("EndpointName", endpoint.DisplayName);
        }
    }

    private static async Task<string> ReadResponseBody(HttpResponse response)
    {
        response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        string responseBody = await new StreamReader(response.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        return $"{responseBody}";
    }
}
```

RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware.cs:

```cs
public class RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Read and log request body data
        string requestBodyPayload = await ReadRequestBody(context.Request);
        LogHelper.RequestPayload = requestBodyPayload;

        // Read and log response body data
        // Copy a pointer to the original response body stream
        var originalResponseBodyStream = context.Response.Body;

        // Create a new memory stream...
        using (var responseBody = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // ...and use that for the temporary response body
            context.Response.Body = responseBody;

            // Continue down the Middleware pipeline, eventually returning to this class
            await _next(context);

            // Copy the contents of the new memory stream (which contains the response) to the original stream, which is then returned to the client.
            await responseBody.CopyToAsync(originalResponseBodyStream);
        }
    }

    private async Task<string> ReadRequestBody(HttpRequest request)
    {
        HttpRequestRewindExtensions.EnableBuffering(request);

        var body = request.Body;
        var buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(request.ContentLength)];
        await request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        string requestBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
        body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        request.Body = body;

        return $"{requestBody}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, what is GetEndpoint() ? it does not seems to be available in Core 3.1 (also not when using IHttpContextAccessor).

Comment: @Yovav Hi. GetEndpoint() is an extension method of HttpContext object. It comes from NuGet package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions 2.2.0

Comment: See my comment for adding extensions app uses.net core 3.0 or later
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61847821/cant-access-httpcontext-extension-methods-in-net-standard/61848663#comment115772877_61848663

Comment: Can anyone help to know where will the log is stored, I have tried this code. I am saving the logs in a text file using the serilog. But the log from here doesn't store in the text file. Is there any separate thing I have to add to this code?

Comment: @aakash as far as I remember, this should be configured in the appsettings.json of your project, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40880261/configuring-serilog-rollingfile-with-appsettings-json)

Comment: @Vladimir thanks i made this work by adding in the appsettings.json

Comment: httpContext.GetEndpoint() does not exist anywhere in .Net 7 even with the additional package installed.

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer is not thread-safe.

> LogHelper.RequestPayload = requestBodyPayload;

This assignment can lead to unexpected logging result when there are multiple concurrent requests. 
Instead of using a static variable I pushed the request body directly in a LogContext property of Serilog.

Answer (score 0):

If logging in to the file we can add the following code with the answer from [@Vladimir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60096660/3811265) in .net core 5.0.

**Add UseSerilog in Program.cs**

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        })
        .UseSerilog((hostingContext, services, loggerConfig) =>
         loggerConfig.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
             .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.FromSource("Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware")).WriteTo.File(path: "Logs/WebHookLog_.log",
                 outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:o}-{RequestBody}-{ResponseBody}-{Host}-{ContentType}-{EndpointName} {NewLine}", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day))
        );
```

**Fields to be added in the appsettings.json:**

```json
"Serilog": {
  "MinimumLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Override": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "WriteTo": [
    { "Name": "Console" },
    {
      "Name": "File",
      "Args": {
        "path": "Logs/applog_.log",
        "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:o} [{Level:u3}] ({SourceContext}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
        "rollingInterval": "Day",
        "retainedFileCountLimit": 7
      }
    }
  ],
  "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName" ],
  "Properties": {
    "Application": "AspNetCoreSerilogDemo"
  }
},
```