# Can't access httpcontext extension methods in .net standard

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-standard, asp.net-core-3.1

I have this .NET Standard library where I want to write a .NET Core middleware.

Inside which I want to do :

```
Endpoint endpoint = httpContext.GetEndpoint();
```

The `GetEndpoint()` extension method can't be resolved.

I have referenced `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` and I have both `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core` packages added to the project.

Is there a solution to this, am I missing something?

Comment: try installing this nuget [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/)

Comment: @neeleshbodgal Doesn't work.

Comment: try to add this https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/2.2.0
 This package work for me

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman : As stated in the question, that was already added.
Does it work for you in a .Net Standard project ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I assume you're writing a middleware for ASP.NET Core 3.1 since you included the "asp.net-core-3.1" tag.

To use that extension, you need to target `netcoreapp3.*` instead of `netstandard2.*`:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
```

(You can see which ASP.NET Core versions that extension is available for in the dropdown menu on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.endpointhttpcontextextensions.getendpoint) page)

You will also need to either:

1. use the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` MSBuild SDK:

   ```
   <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
   ```
2. or add the framework reference:

   ```
   <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
   ```

Reference: [Use ASP.NET Core APIs in a class library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework)

Comment: That's what I've just realized, those extensions aren't available in .Net standard, I had to target core 3.1
Complete answer, accepting, upvoting.

Comment: +1. This answer is also useful when trying to use GetEnpoint in a class library (as opposed to using it in a Web API project). Unfortunately, simply adding the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions as indicated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.endpointhttpcontextextensions.getendpoint?view=aspnetcore-3.1) is not enough.

Comment: "With the release of .NET Core 3.0, many ASP.NET Core assemblies are no longer published to NuGet as packages. 
Projects using the Microsoft.NET.Sdk or Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor SDK must reference ASP.NET Core to use ASP.NET Core APIs in the shared framework." 
Quote from Microsoft(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework)
Add following lines to your .csproj file
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>