# how to customize output serilog

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

hi everyone how can i get this output

```
{
    "@t": "2020-11-03T16:40:21.6133998Z",
    "@m": "HTTP \"POST\" \"/api/Email/SendEmail\" responded 200 in 1.0358 ms",
    "@i": "62d0885c",
    "CorrelationId": "",
    "Host": "localhost:32768",
    "Protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
    "Scheme": "http",
    "ContentType": null,
    "EndpointName": "Email.Controllers.EmailController.SendEmail (Email)",
    "RequestMethod": "POST",
    "RequestPath": "/api/Email/SendEmail",
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "Elapsed": 1.0358,
    "SourceContext": "Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware",
    "RequestId": "",
    "SpanId": "|55f14a36-4918a3efd4f265b9.",
    "TraceId": "55f14a36-4918a3efd4f265b9",
    "ParentId": "",
    "ConnectionId": "0HM402S7EC249"
}
```

but when i invoke my controller i see and run application i see that

thats class how i setting my Serilog,what i do wrong

```
 public class LogConfig
    {
        public static void Configure()
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
               .WriteTo.Console(new RenderedCompactJsonFormatter())
              .CreateLogger();
        }

        public static void EnrichFromRequest(IDiagnosticContext diagnosticContext, HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            diagnosticContext.Set("RequestScheme", httpContext.Request.Host.Value);
            diagnosticContext.Set("Headers", httpContext.Request.Scheme);
        } 
    }
```

PS

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Here are all steps you need to follow: [link](https://nblumhardt.com/2019/10/serilog-in-aspnetcore-3/#plugging-into-aspnet-core-with-useserilog)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three JSON formatters provided by the Serilog project:

- `Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter` - This is the historical default shipped in the Serilog package. It produces a complete rendering of the log event and supports a few configuration options.
- `Serilog.Formatting.Compact.CompactJsonFormatter` - A newer, more space-efficient JSON formatter shipped in Serilog.Formatting.Compact.
- `Serilog.Formatting.Compact.RenderedCompactJsonFormatter` - Also shipped in Serilog.Formatting.Compact, this formatter pre-renders message templates into text.

You could refer the following steps and use `Serilog.Formatting.Compact` to customize Serilog output:

1. Install `Serilog.AspNetCore` via Nuget.
2. Configure to use `Serilog`:

   ```
    public class Program
    {
        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            // CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
           .MinimumLevel.Debug()
           .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
           .Enrich.FromLogContext()
           .WriteTo.File(new CompactJsonFormatter(), "log20201104.json")
           .CreateLogger();

            try
            {
                Log.Information("Starting web host");
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
                return 0;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
                return 1;
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
   ```

   Remember to add the following reference:

   ```
    using Serilog;
    using Serilog.Events;
    using Serilog.Formatting.Compact;
   ```
3. According to your code, it seems that you want to log the request and response information, if that is the case, you could also create a `SerilogRequestLogger` Middleware. Like this:

   ```
    public class SerilogRequestLogger
    {
        readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public SerilogRequestLogger(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            if (next == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            if (httpContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContext));

            // Push the user name into the log context so that it is included in all log entries
            LogContext.PushProperty("UserName", httpContext.User.Identity.Name);

            // Getting the request body is a little tricky because it's a stream
            // So, we need to read the stream and then rewind it back to the beginning
            string requestBody = "";
            HttpRequestRewindExtensions.EnableBuffering(httpContext.Request);
            Stream body = httpContext.Request.Body;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(httpContext.Request.ContentLength)];
            await httpContext.Request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            requestBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
            body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            httpContext.Request.Body = body;

            Log.ForContext("RequestHeaders", httpContext.Request.Headers.ToDictionary(h => h.Key, h => h.Value.ToString()), destructureObjects: true)
               .ForContext("RequestBody", requestBody)
               .Debug("Request information {RequestMethod} {RequestPath} information", httpContext.Request.Method, httpContext.Request.Path);

            Log.Information(string.Format("Request Body: {0} ", requestBody));

            var exampleUser = new WebApplication2User { Id = "1001", UserName = "Adam", SecurityStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString() };
            Log.Information("Created {@User} on {Created}", exampleUser, DateTime.Now);
            // The reponse body is also a stream so we need to:
            // - hold a reference to the original response body stream
            // - re-point the response body to a new memory stream
            // - read the response body after the request is handled into our memory stream
            // - copy the response in the memory stream out to the original response stream
            using (var responseBodyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var originalResponseBodyReference = httpContext.Response.Body;
                httpContext.Response.Body = responseBodyMemoryStream;

                await _next(httpContext);

                httpContext.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                var responseBody = await new StreamReader(httpContext.Response.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
                httpContext.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                Log.ForContext("RequestBody", requestBody)
                   .ForContext("ResponseBody", responseBody)
                   .Debug("Response information {RequestMethod} {RequestPath} {statusCode}", httpContext.Request.Method, httpContext.Request.Path, httpContext.Response.StatusCode);

                await responseBodyMemoryStream.CopyToAsync(originalResponseBodyReference);
            }
        }
    }
   ```
4. Configure the `SerilogRequestLogger` Middleware in the `Configure` method:

   ```
     app.UseMiddleware<SerilogRequestLogger>();
   ```

Then, you could use the following code to log information:

```
            var exampleUser = new WebApplication2User { Id = "1001", UserName = "Adam", SecurityStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString() };
            Log.Information("Created {@User} on {Created}", exampleUser, DateTime.Now);
```

the result like this:

> {"@t":"2020-11-04T14:19:23.2065796Z","@mt":"Created {@User} on
> {Created}","User":{"Id":"1001","Age":0,"UserName":"Adam","NormalizedUserName":null,"Email":null,"NormalizedEmail":null,"EmailConfirmed":false,"PasswordHash":null,"SecurityStamp":"11/4/2020
> 10:19:23
> PM","ConcurrencyStamp":"ca564733-9524-446f-8103-dd211cf8b44c","PhoneNumber":null,"PhoneNumberConfirmed":false,"TwoFactorEnabled":false,"LockoutEnd":null,"LockoutEnabled":false,"AccessFailedCount":0,"$type":"WebApplication2User"},"Created":"2020-11-04T22:19:23.2060830+08:00","UserName":null,"RequestId":"80000080-0005-fd00-b63f-84710c7967bb","RequestPath":"/Home/Privacy","SpanId":"|e29bfdb0-4bd9f6a34acb24d8.","TraceId":"e29bfdb0-4bd9f6a34acb24d8","ParentId":""}

Reference:

[Formatting JSON](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output)

[Serilog.Formatting.Compact](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-formatting-compact)

[How to add 'request body' in serilog's output .net core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63573551/how-to-add-request-body-in-serilogs-output-net-core/63579077#63579077)