# Serilog - logging specific properties from request body on error

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, serilog, error-logging

I tried the following answer:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/68493795/897326

Namely this:

```
 options.EnrichDiagnosticContext = (diagnosticContext, httpContext) =>
   {
     // string body = your logic to get body from httpContext.Request.Body
        diagnosticContext.Set("Body", body);
   };
```

But in my case body is an empty string. My code for reading body from httpContext is based on this solution:

- https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1638#issuecomment-363084402

And it works in my custom middleware that I created for global exception handling. It does not use Serilog though. Just some quick poor man's approach to structured logging via Newtonsoft serialization.

I found this enricher on nuget:

- https://github.com/trenoncourt/serilog-enrichers-aspnetcore-httpcontext

But it seems outdated, and the Serilog syntax has changed since then.

I also checked this related official Serilog ticket which was closed.

- https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/1506

Is this workflow of adding custom properties from http request not supported natively by Serilog? Quote from their github repo:

> Thanks for raising this. I think copying and modifying https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/blob/dev/src/Serilog.AspNetCore/AspNetCore/RequestLoggingMiddleware.cs will be the simplest way forwards (I agree this is a bit unfortunate

For example, if a request has a field called patientId, log that. Because there are infinite number of ways to log properties from http context, it's fine to ask developer to provide that custom method. But creating a custom middleware for this sounds like an overkill. Also multiple middlewares might not work well together.

Is there a way to log custom properties from http request? I have my own global exception middleware, but not sure how to make it work together with Serilog. Or any other option. Main requirement - custom properties should **ONLY** be logged in case of an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround I found is manually logging the error from my global exception middleware. In Program.cs, remove the following line:

```
app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
```

Then in middleware, add

```
using Serilog;
// ... some code here, then in catch block
Log.Error("Unhandled exception occured when processing request {@errorRequest}.",
                                                                 errorRequest);
// ... more code, set 500 status and custom props on response
```

Where `errorRequest` would contain the necessary properties.

Comment: For the lack of better options, I will accept this as an answer after 2 days timeout. Feel free to post more answers - I will review and change accepted to that if it's better.

Answer (score 2):

You can UseSerilogRequestLogging to log request/response details as described in [Serilog logging web-api methods, adding context properties inside middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60076922/serilog-logging-web-api-methods-adding-context-properties-inside-middleware/60096660#60096660)

To log only errors/warnings you can specify  params

```
app.UseSerilogRequestLogging(
    x =>
    {
        x.GetLevel = (context, _, ex) =>
            context.Response.StatusCode >= StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest || ex != null
                ? LogEventLevel.Warning
                : LogEventLevel.Debug;
        x.EnrichDiagnosticContext = SerilogHelper.EnrichFromRequest;
        x.IncludeQueryInRequestPath = true;
    });
```

And in production enable only logLevel information or greater