# Configure Serilog File sink to use one log file per application run

Tags: .net, logging, serilog

I want to configure Serilog to create one log file per app run.
File name should be based on current date/time:
**1st run:** log_20180413_1020.txt
**2nd run:** log_20180413_1033.txt

I didn't find how to do it in any File sink (Rolling, Alternative..)
Any clue?

Comment: I posted answer to similar question... [https://stackoverflow.com/a/54537396/4331722](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54537396/4331722)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Configure the [`Serilog.Sinks.File`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file) sink without any rolling period or size limit, and add the timestamp to the log filename when you configure logging at startup:

```cs
string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmm");
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.File($"log{timestamp}.txt")
    .CreateLogger();
```

Per the [Rolling Policies](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file#serilogsinksfile-----) section of the README:

> Specifying both `rollingInterval` and `rollOnFileSizeLimit` will cause both policies to be applied, while ***specifying neither will result in all events being written to a single file.***

Comment: How can this be achieved from appsetting.json? instead of code.

Comment: Also, I'd prefer to have `rollingInterval` and `rollOnFileSizeLimit` to be turned on in addition to roll per run too..

Comment: See the [configuration package](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration), it's extremely flexible, it can apply arbitrary settings through some fairly advanced reflection.

Comment: This still logs to the same file if the application is run twice in the same minute.

Comment: @Benjamin4991 ... true, but trivial to add `ss` to the timestamp if that's a use-case of concern.

Comment: @McGuireV10 I tried this and did not work. "specifying neither will result in all events being written to a single file."...I think that means it will write all logs to a single file (which is what I am seeing) not a single log file per app run.

Answer (score 2):

This is my approach for [`Serilog.Sinks.File`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file) and [`Serilog.Settings.Configuration`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration). It's an evolution of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49824247/8212196), but also using an `appsettings.json`.

Sample of the `appsettings.json`:

```
"Serilog": {
  "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Debug", "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
  "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
  "WriteTo": {
    "DebugSink": "Debug",
    "FileSink": {
      "Name": "File",
      "Args": {
        "path": "%LOCALAPPDATA%/Company/Application/{timestamp}.log"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please look at how I handle array declaration in the `WriteTo` - it is on purpose to have an easier to replace a `{timestamp}` placeholder — details about [`WriteTo` can find in this section](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration#writeto-enrich-auditto-destructure-sections).

Now, let's configure the logger using the config from `appsettings.json`:

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .Build();

const string serilogFileSinkPath = "Serilog:WriteTo:FileSink:Args:path";

if (configuration.GetSection(serilogFileSinkPath).Exists())
{
    var filePath = configuration[serilogFileSinkPath];
    configuration[serilogFileSinkPath] = filePath.Replace("{timestamp}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"));
}

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
    .CreateLogger();
```

The code reads the configuration.
Next, it checks if the given section that contains the file path is present - if yes, then the replacement of the placeholder happens.
Now configuration has all the needed data, so it can be used to configure the logger.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is still trying to find out how to achieve this from `appsettings.json`, I've ended up with this workaround:

```
// Add this line before creating a logger
UpdateLogFilePath(configuration);

// This is your existing Serilog logger creation logic
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
    .CreateLogger();
```

Implementation of the `UpdateLogFilePath` method:

```
private static void UpdateLogFilePath(IConfigurationRoot configuration)
{
    // A configuration key pattern we are going to look for
    string pattern = "^Serilog:WriteTo.*Args:path$";

    foreach (var kvp in configuration.AsEnumerable())
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(kvp.Key, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) 
            && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(kvp.Value))
        {
            // Format a file path in the logger configuration
            configuration[kvp.Key] = string.Format(kvp.Value, DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
}
```

Sample of the `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "log_{0:yyyyMMdd_HHmm}.txt"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```