# Is it possible to configure Serilog to truncate (i.e. make empty) the log file for each new process?

Tags: serilog

Moving from nlog to serilog, I would like my .NET framework desktop application to reuse a statically-named log file each time I run it, but to clear out the contents of the file with each new process. Is it possible to configure serilog this way?

[This is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49822263/configure-serilog-file-sink-to-use-one-log-file-per-application-run), but it's not quite the same. In the linked question, the user uses a new log file each time with a unique filename. In my case, I want to use the same log file name each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not something Serilog can do for you as of this writing.

[Serilog.Sinks.File is hard-coded to open the file with `FileMode.Append`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.File/Sinks/File/FileSink.cs#L83) thus if the file already exists, it will always append contents at the end of the file.

[FileLifecycleHooks](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file#extensibility) allows you to intercept when the file is being opened, and that would give you an opportunity to remove the contents of the file (by calling `SetLength(0)` on the stream), but unfortunately the stream implementation that Serilog.Sinks.File uses ([WriteCountingStream](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.File/Sinks/File/WriteCountingStream.cs)) [does not support SetLength](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.File/Sinks/File/WriteCountingStream.cs#L64-L67).

**Your best bet is to just truncate or delete the log file yourself at the start of the app**, and let Serilog create a new one.

e.g.

```
// Ensure that the log file is empty 
using (var fs = File.OpenWrite("mylog.log")) { fs.SetLength(0); }

// ... Configure Serilog pipeline
```

Comment: I went with the suggestion from @c-augusto-proiete (thanks a bunch) my code looks something like this a few lines before calling `new LoggerConfiguration()`: ...

`var f = new FileInfo("mylog.log");`
`if (f.Exists)`
`using (var s = f.Open(FileMode.Truncate))`
`s.Close();`

Comment: That works fine. You can omit the `Close` as you're calling `Dispose` already via `using`.  An slightly shorter alternative would be to always create an empty file without checking if it exists e.g. `using (var fs = File.OpenWrite(@"C:\Temp\mylog.log")) { fs.SetLength(0); }`